# Property about auto-equivalence of categories

Tags: category-theory, triangulated-categories

Let $ T : \mathcal C \to C $ be an equivalence of categories with quasi inverse $G$ ; i.e., there exist natural isomorphisms $ TG \ \overset{\eta_{1}}  \to id_{\mathcal C} $ and $ GT \ \overset{\eta_{2}}  \to id_{\mathcal C} $.

Now let X be an  object of $\mathcal{C}$.

Then **$T(\eta_{2_{X}}) = \eta_{1_{TX}} : TGT(X) \to T(X)$** ?

※ This question originates from next statement

Let $ (\mathcal{D} , T)$ be a triangulated category and $ X \overset{f} \to Y \overset{g} \to Z \overset{h} \to TX$ a distinguished triangle.

Then $ GX \overset{-G(f)} \to GY \overset{-G(g)} \to GZ \overset{k} \to TGX $, where
$ k : GZ \overset{-Gh} \to GTX \overset{-\eta_{2_X}}\cong X \overset{-\eta_{1_X}^{-1}}\cong TGX $
, is also distinguished triangle?

If our original question is true, then we get isomorphism of triangles

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
 TGX \ &  \ \ra {TG(f)} \ & TGY & \ra{TG(g)} \ & TGZ \ & \ra{-T(k)} \  &T^{2}GX  \\
 \da{\eta_{1_{X}} \cong} & & \da{\eta_{1_{Y}} \cong} & & \da{\eta_{1_{Z}} \cong} & & \da{T(\eta_{1_{X}}) \cong}  \\
 X & \ra{f} & Y & \ra{g} & Z & \ra{h} & TX  \\
\end{array}
$$

So,  $TGX \overset{TG(f)} \to TGY \overset{TG(g)} \to TGZ \overset{-T(k)} \to T^{2}GX $ is also distinguished triangle. So,from the axiom TR3 of triangulated category applying repeatedly to $ GX \overset{-G(f)} \to GY \overset{-G(g)} \to GZ \overset{k} \to TGX $, we have that  $ GX \overset{-G(f)} \to GY \overset{-G(g)} \to GZ \overset{k} \to TGX $is distingushed triangle.

Comment: It's not necessarily true, but *we can choose* such a quasi-inverse $G$ for any equivalence of categories: namely any equivalence can be adjusted to be an *adjoint equivalence*.

Comment: Wow, Thanks!. I didn't know about the fact. I found a literature containing fact you present(e.g. Categories for working mathematician), and I become closer to completion of proof of my original statement beared in mind. Thanks for your short but valuable comment ! Good day

Comment: [On the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+equivalence) there is graphical proof of this fact.

Comment: Yes. I also searched nlab for adjoint equivalence. Thank you ~